# How can I output the Collection's products from a section using schema collection in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I am trying to display the selected collection from the schema(that user can select from the Shopify admin panel) and loop it in a slider to display.
Please let me know how to display it on the frontend as same as I displayed content.

**Here is my Schema Code:**
{% comment %}
** Single featured collection - homepage partial **
- Draggable section
{% endcomment %}

```
{% include 'include-collection-slider' %}

{% schema %}
    {
        "name" : "collection_tab",
        "class": "featured-collection-section",
        "settings" :[
                        {
                          "type": "text",
                          "id": "title",
                          "label": "Header Name",
                          "default": "SHOP BY NEED"
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "collection",
                          "id": "collection1",
                          "label": "Collection 1"
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "collection",
                          "id": "collection2",
                          "label": "Collection 2"
                        },
                      
                        {
                          "type": "radio",
                          "id": "collection_style",
                          "label": "Collection layout",
                          "default": "grid",
                          "options": [
                            {
                              "value": "slider",
                              "label": "Slider"
                            },
                            {
                              "value": "grid",
                              "label": "Grid"
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "header",
                          "content": "Products"
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "range",
                          "id": "products_per",
                          "label": "Products per row",
                          "min": 2,
                          "max": 7,
                          "step": 1,
                          "default": 3
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "range",
                          "id": "products_limit",
                          "label": "Limit products",
                          "min": 2,
                          "max": 50,
                          "step": 1,
                          "default": 9
                        }
                    ],
        "blocks" : [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "name": "Category Tab Name",
                    
        "settings" :[
                            {
                                "type": "text",
                                "id": "tab",
                                "label": "Tab Name"                                     
                            },
                            {
                            "type": "text",
                            "id": "heading",
                            "label": "Heading"
                            },
                            {
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "id": "collection_description",
                            "label": "Show Description"
                            },
                            {
                            "type": "richtext",
                            "id": "collection_content",
                            "label": "Show Content"
                            },
                            
                            {
                            "type": "collection",
                            "id": "collection",
                            "label": "Collection"
                            },
                        
                            {
                            "type": "radio",
                            "id": "collection_style",
                            "label": "Collection layout",
                            "default": "grid",
                            "options": [
                              {
                                "value": "slider",
                                "label": "Slider"
                              },
                              {
                                "value": "grid",
                                "label": "Grid"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                        {
                          "type": "header",
                          "content": "Products"
                        },
                        {
                        "type": "range",
                        "id": "products_per",
                        "label": "Products per row",
                        "min": 2,
                        "max": 7,
                        "step": 1,
                        "default": 3
                      },
                        {
                      "type": "range",
                      "id": "products_limit",
                      "label": "Limit products",
                      "min": 2,
                      "max": 50,
                      "step": 1,
                      "default": 9
                    }
                  ]
                
                }
            ],
      "presets": [{
    "name": "Collection Slider",
    "category": "Collection",
    "settings": {

    }
  }]
    }
{% endschema %}

****Here is my Liquid Code:****
{% if type == 'block' %}
  {% assign title = block.settings.title %}
  {% assign settingHeading = block.settings.heading %}
  {% assign settingCollection = block.settings.collection %}
  {% assign collection_style = block.settings.collection_style %}
  {% assign collection_description = block.settings.collection_description %}
  {% assign products_per = block.settings.products_per %}
  {% assign products_limit = block.settings.products_limit %}
{% else %}
  {% assign title = section.settings.title %}
  {% assign settingCollection = section.settings.collection %}
  {% assign collection_style = section.settings.collection_style %}
  {% assign collection_description = section.settings.collection_description %}
  {% assign products_per = section.settings.products_per %}
  {% assign products_limit = section.settings.products_limit %}
{% endif %}

 {% assign limit = products_limit %}
  {% if collection_style == 'slider' %}
    {% assign col = settingCollection | handleize %}
    {% assign products = collections[col].products %}
    {% assign product_count = collections[col].all_products_count %}
    {% assign per_slide = products_per %}
  {% endif %}


  {% if settingCollection == blank   %}
    {%- assign section_onboarding = true -%}
    {% comment %}assign product length to be selected limit for onboarding{% endcomment %}
    {% assign products_length = products_limit | plus: 0 %}
  {% else %}
    {%- assign section_onboarding = false -%}
  {% endif %}

<div class="container featured_products product-{{ collection_style }}">
  <div class="sixteen columns center homepage_content">
        <h2 class="title">{{ title }}</h2>
  </div>
     <div class="tabs">
        <!--Collection Tabs Code Start -->
      <ul class="tabs-thumbs">
        {%for block in section.blocks %}
          <li class="tabs-thumb">
            <a>{{block.settings.tab}}</a> 
        </li>
         {%endfor%}
      </ul>
      <!--Collection Tabs Code End -->
       
      <ul class="tabs-panels">
        {% for block in section.blocks%}
 
        
        
        <li class="tabs-panel">
            <div class="sixteen row collection-slider">
                <div class="six columns center homepage_content">
                    <div class="section clearfix featured-collection__description">
                    <div style="display:inline-flex;margin-bottom: 15px; font-weight: 900; color: red;">
                      Collection Name:{{block.settings.collection | products}}<br>
                      {{popular_product}}
                    </div>
                        {{block.settings.collection_content}}
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
              
              
               <div class="ten columns js-product-slider homepage-product-slider full-width--true  featured-collection__products">
                <div class="container js-product-slider homepage-product-slider full-width--true 
                            {% if per_slide == 2 or per_slide == 4 or per_slide == 6 %}
                            even-num-slides{% endif %} featured-collection__products">
                  {% if section_onboarding == false %}
                    {% if product_count > 0 %}
                      {% render 'product-slider',
                              limit: limit,
                              products: products,
                              per_slide: products_per,
                                featured_collection: col
                      %}
                  
                    {% endif %}
                   {% endif %}
              </div>
            </div>
            </div> 
        </li>
        {%endfor%}
    </ul>
    </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A **"type": "collection"** will return the collection handle, then you will need to do:

```
{% for item in collections[section.settings.collection2].products %}
    <div class="slider-item">
        {{ item.title }}
        {{ item.price | money }}
        {{ item.featured_image | img_url: '250x' }}
        {{ item.url }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Put that inside the slider code and change the code as you need.